# Jquery not firing on checking the checkbox

Tags: jquery

Hello guys i am doing remember me functionality for my site when a user checks the checkbox the username and password should me stored in a cookie. when i check the checkbox nothing happens no event is fired

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#menu").click(function(e) {
        $(".nav").slideToggle();        
    });
    if ($('#remember').attr("checked")) {
        alert("check box checked");
        var username = $('#username').attr("value");
        var password = $('#password').attr("value");
        // set cookies to expire in 14 days
        $.cookie('username', username, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('password', password, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });
    } else {
        // reset cookies
        $.cookie('username', null);
        $.cookie('password', null);
        $.cookie('remember', null);
    }

});
```

Comment: First you should use the `change` event, not `click` to include people who navigate with the keyboard. Secondly, your `if` statement should be *inside* the event handler. Lastly, ***never store plaintext user credentials in a cookie***. What you have now is a massive security flaw.

Comment: The click event is for something else. #remember is my checkbox simply if someone checks it should store the values in a cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put if and else condition only, but this code will get fire on document ready and not on checkbox check. Add checkbox change event handler and put your script inside it, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#menu").click(function(e) {
        $(".nav").slideToggle();        
    });
   // register a change event handler
    $('#remember').change(function(){
       //Use $(this), which is the instance of clicked checkbox
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // you can use is(":checked")
          alert("check box checked");
          var username = $('#username').attr("value");
          var password = $('#password').attr("value");
          // set cookies to expire in 14 days
          $.cookie('username', username, { expires: 14 });
          $.cookie('password', password, { expires: 14 });
          $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });
      } else {
          // reset cookies
          $.cookie('username', null);
          $.cookie('password', null);
          $.cookie('remember', null);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

bind the event to the checkbox's click:

```
$('#remember').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("checked"));
});
```